# MySQL Inner Join involving three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine-orm, inner-join

I am working with four tables:

- query,
- store,
- cluster_group,
- tv_region

I want to retrieve query records belonging to a particular TV Region record.

A query record either belongs to a record in the store or cluster_group tables. The query table has 'store_id' and 'cluster_group_id' columns. Either will be null whilst the other will refer to a record in the store or cluster_group table. The store and cluster_group tables both have a 'tv_region_id' column.

To retrieve query records that belong to a TV Region record that has an id = 2, I wrote the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT query.id AS query_id, cluster_group.name as cluster_name, cluster_group.tv_region_id as cluster_tv_region, store.store_name
FROM query
INNER JOIN cluster_group
ON cluster_group.id=query.cluster_group_id

INNER JOIN store
ON store.id=query.store_id

WHERE cluster_group.tv_region_id = 2
AND store.tv_region_id = 2;
```

The problem is that it returns zero records even though there are query records that belong to the specified TV Region (via a cluster group or store record). I may have misunderstood how 'inner join' works.

I'm working with **Doctrine 2** and have attempted the query using the left join but it still returns nothing, I guess this is because its returning null values too. How do I get it to return only the query records I am interested in and no null values?

Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to retrieve the relevant query records.

Comment: Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, which will return null columns when there is no matching row, while an INNER JOIN (that you have used) will return nothing (as there needs to be a row on both). Alternatively use 2 queries UNIONed together.

Comment: Can Doctrine select from a view?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use OUTER joins, or possibly LEFT

INNER joins will only return data where there is a matching record on both sides. As you state in your question you only get a match on one side or the other, therefore there is never going to be a matching record across both store and cluster

Jeff Atwood has a good explanation of the join types on his blog http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT query.id AS query_id, cluster_group.name as cluster_name, cluster_group.tv_region_id as cluster_tv_region, store.store_name
FROM query
LEFT OUTER JOIN cluster_group
ON cluster_group.id=query.cluster_group_id
AND cluster_group.tv_region_id = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN store
ON store.id=query.store_id
AND store.tv_region_id = 2
```

EDIT - no experience of doctrine, but you could try using a UNION:-

```
SELECT query.id AS query_id, cluster_group.name as cluster_name, cluster_group.tv_region_id as cluster_tv_region, NULL AS store_name
FROM query
INNER JOIN cluster_group
ON cluster_group.id=query.cluster_group_id
AND cluster_group.tv_region_id = 2
UNION
SELECT query.id AS query_id, NULL as cluster_name, NULL as cluster_tv_region, store.store_name
FROM query
INNER JOIN store
ON store.id=query.store_id
AND store.tv_region_id = 2
```

Comment: I am working with Doctrine, so my query is written in DQL. I applied the left join but this still returns zero records presumably because of the null values.

Comment: Just discovered that outer joins are not possible in Doctrine.

Comment: Edited to suggest trying a UNION

Comment: UNION makes sense but also not supported by Doctrine. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this for me:

```
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
inner join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
```